# AccuRev visual studio 2012 plugin Not found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, accurev

I have installed AccuRev plugin, but visual studio 2012 cant find it under:

```
Options-->Source Control--> plug-in selection-->current source control
```

any solution or alternative plugin for this?

Comment: Did you try installing the plugin again or rebooting your machine?

Comment: I did, and it did work the third time. after using it for about 5 min it disappeared again. accurev is the worst version control i ever worked on.

Comment: What version of AccuRev are you using?  What version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: I use AccuRev 6.2 and Plug-In "Version 2014.3".

Comment: Since you are on the latest release, I would contact AccuRev support for assistance regarding this problem your having.